# Internal server error on Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

I was working with **paypal** . Everything worked fine , when I changed the settings to sandbox , The code is prompting the following error.

**Internal Server Error**

I tried searching , people are referring to look the **error log** but it did not do any good because the error log was empty .  Please let me know if there is a fix for this ?

Comment: which **exactly** error.log  was empty?

Comment: Please read how to create a minimal working example and ask the question

Comment: all the logs , i wrote 

tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an issue like that , The problem was my **.htaccess** file was corrupted , so I renamed it for the time being. And it worked . Try it . And make a new .htaccess if it helps . I hope it helps.

Comment: This works . Why sandbox has to do anything with my .htaccess?